# Apache 502 Proxy error when I add CMD cron to php Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, apache, cron

I have two Docker containers built from `php:8.0.15-fpm` (**php**) and `httpd:2.4` (**apache**) images.

In the PHP Dockerfile I have added at the end `CMD cron`.

When I do this apache is crashing with error:
`502 Proxy error`

I am not sure why does apache crashes when I add `CMD cron` at the end.

The code in the Dockerfile for cron is copied from here https://github.com/cheyer/docker-cron/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: A Docker container only runs one process, so if you set the container to run a cron daemon, that runs _instead of_ the php-fpm interpreter.  You can override the `CMD` when you start the container (by putting a command after the `docker run image-name`, or by using a Compose `command:`) and you might run two containers off the same image, one running the default (`php-fpm`) command and the other overridden to run the cron daemon.

Comment: I can create a separate container only for cron. The problem is that I also need PHP in order to run the command the cron job calls. (ex: php bin/console). What do you recommand ?

Comment: You can use the same image, running a different container with a different command.

Comment: done. thank you for the suggestion.